# Typechecking of array of class in function interface

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, when creating a function interface and using that as the type expected by another function (i.e. a function expecting a callback), and the parameter of the callback function is an array of a class. The typechecking does not seem to be able to handle it:

```
"use strict";

class A {
  /* no-op */
}

interface C {
  (s: Array<A>): void
}

const B = (c: C) => {
  c(["Hello World!"]);
};

B((s: Array<A>) => {console.log("Should work", s)});
B((s: A) => {console.log("Should not work", s)});
```

In this case I believe the second call to B should fail typechecking, as it does when not expecting an array of class instances, but instead a primitive such as string:

```
"use strict";

interface C {
  (s: Array<string>): void
}

const B = (c: C) => {
  c(["Hello World!"]);
};

B((s: Array<string>) => {console.log("Should work", s)});
B((s: string) => {console.log("Should not work", s)});
```

Which fails typechecking with:

```
test.ts(12,3): error TS2345: Argument of type '(s: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'C'.
  Types of parameters 's' and 's' are incompatible.
    Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I could not find anything regarding this when attempting to search for answers and I'm using TypeScript 2.3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not getting any compilation errors is that your `A` class is empty and since [typescript is based on structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) the empty class/object matches everything, for example:

```
class A {}

let a1: A = 4;
let a2: A = true;
let a3: A = "string";
```

All fine, with no compilation errors.

When you introduce a member into class `A` then you start getting errors:

```
class A {
    dummy: number;
}

let a1: A = 4; // ERROR: Type '4' is not assignable to type 'A'
let a2: A = true; // ERROR: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'A'
let a3: A = "string"; // ERROR: Type '"string"' is not assignable to type 'A'

const B = (c: C) => {
    c(["Hello World!"]); // ERROR: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A[]'
};

B((s: A) => { console.log("Should not work", s); }); // ERROR: Argument of type '(s: A) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'C'
```

Comment: Thank you Nitzan for the quick answer and reference to the documentation!